# how i can use mouse button 4-5 (gamer) with python?

Tags: python, mouse, pyautogui

I am trying to use mouse button 4 and 5 for a program but I can only use the right, left and middle button with pyautogui, do i need another library? or what? can somebody help me?

```
while True:
    data=conexion.read(size=1)
    if data ==bytes('7','utf-8'):
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    elif data == bytes('4','utf-8'):
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    elif data == bytes('8','utf-8'):
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
    elif data == bytes('C', 'utf-8'):
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'u')
    elif data == bytes('*', 'utf-8'):
        buscar_cs()
    elif data == bytes('A', 'utf-8'):
        for i in range(5):
            pyautogui.moveTo(777,363)
            pyautogui.click(x=777,y=363,button='middle')
            pyautogui.scroll(-244)
            time.sleep(0.50)
    elif data == bytes('2', 'utf-8'):
        for i in range(5):
            pyautogui.moveTo(1022,284)
            pyautogui.click(x=1022,y=284,button='left')
            pyautogui.scroll(-244)
            time.sleep(0.25)
    elif data == bytes('D','utf-8'):
        pyautogui.alert(text="Cerrado", title='ALERTA', button='OK')
        break
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Based on the documentation (try `help(pyautogui.click)`) it looks like the `click` method only supports left, right, and middle clicks. You may need another library, or there may be some other function in `pyautogui` (though I doubt it). If you come across a way to do this in python before someone answers the question, it would be helpful if you answer your own question with your solution to help future users.

Comment: I was able to do it but, i could not understand somethings of my code.... maybe I need more experience for this library

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do! but we need another library called "**pynput**".

**Button.x1** and **Button.x2** are mouse button 4 and 5

code for press boton:

```
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

#press boton
mouse=Controller()
mouse.click(Button.x1)
time.sleep(1)
mouse.click(Button.x2)
time.sleep(1)
```

code for listening:

```
import time
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed == True and str(button)=="Button.x1":
        print("pressed x1")
    return

listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_click=on_click)
listener.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Consider checking if there is any error on your answer.  ``` listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_click=on_click)
listener.start()````   I am not 100% sure, but maybe you have made TYPO mistake.  It would be nice if you double check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at the `__init__.py`, from this module, you'll see a piece of code like this in the function `click()`:

```
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    # Check for valid button arg on Linux:
    if button not in (LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT, PRIMARY, SECONDARY, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7):
        raise PyAutoGUIException(
            "button argument must be one of ('left', 'middle', 'right', 'primary', 'secondary', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)"
        )
else:
    # Check for valid button arg on Windows and macOS:
    if button not in (LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT, PRIMARY, SECONDARY, 1, 2, 3):
        raise PyAutoGUIException(
            "button argument must be one of ('left', 'middle', 'right', 'primary', 'secondary', 1, 2, 3)"
        )
```

From here we can see that, for some reason, linux can receive the "extra buttons" that others OS can't.

By the way, you'll see an error a little behind that OS if/else check (mentioned above):

```
button = button.lower()
```

Here, if you try to pass any number as argument to the `click()` function you'll get that `PyAutoGUIException`, so I recommend you to change this line or make some verification like:

```
if type(button) == str:
    button = button.lower()
```